# Cutting a LEGO baseplate

Tags: building, customization

I have a regular LEGO baseplate that I'd like to shave down to fit into a car travel kit. Does anyone have experiencing cutting a baseplate? I'd love tips on tools or technique!

Comment: What sort of size are you trying to cut the baseplate down to? Unless you plan to permanently attach the baseplate to something, you might be better off getting a few plates and using those. 8x8 or 8x16 plates are large enough for a small base while still being easy to transport.

Comment: I do want to permanently modify it. I only need to take about two rows off.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to score the baseplate with a straightedge and knife. Once you've made a deep enough cut, you should be able to bend and break the plate where you've scored it. You may want to sand the edge to clean it up a bit.

[image: scoring]

[image: score and bend]

There's a more detailed set of instructions in [this Instructable](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Cut-Lego-Base-Plate/?ALLSTEPS).

Comment: You are a beautiful person - thank you! This is EXACTLY what I needed!

Comment: I'll also add that I used a nail file to smooth the edges when I was done and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I was shocked at first to see someone cutting a black baseplate: I didn't even know that part existed; it must be rare. Who could do such a thing?! Oh, it's a clone part. Carry on.

Answer (score 2):

Press down 8 x 2 / 10 x 2 / 16 x 2 plates etc. to the board to give you a cutting line, make sure they are firmly pressed down.

On a flat surface, gently score the board tight up to the edge of the plates 2 or three times then firmly bend to snap the board and finish by trimming a small 45 degree.

Cut at the new sharp corners and hand finish with fine rubbing down paper. I retail vintage / used Lego and we often cut down damaged boards to make smaller ones and this method works well so long as you don't try to cut too hard and lose the line up against the guiding plates.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use a sandpaper. First use a clamp to fix the part you want to cut, then use sandpaper. Instead of trying to cut it i think you should grind it with sandpaper.